# SignalR - Problem in Fetching data from view

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have created Web Api with SignalR to fetch data  from database object as a View. When i was updating the table which are connected to view, the data is not fetching and the updated data is not showing in the html page. we have created two separate solutions in 1st solution we have api and MyHub class to call the client function displayStatus. In 2nd solution we have html and displayStatus() function. Am not able to call the displayStatus() function from MyHub class which is in another solution i.e 1st solution.

My Code:
ApiController:

`using SignalRMVC;
namespace SignalRWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/GetData")]
        public string GetData(string cri="")
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStrSignalR"].ConnectionString);
            string query = @"SELECT (*my query comes here*)";
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);`

```
        cmd.Notification = null;
        SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStrSignalR"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var result = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new PropertyClassName()
                        {
                            property1 = x.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                            property1 = x.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        }).ToList();

        string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

        return jsonResult;
    }
    private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        MyHubMvc.Show();
    }
}
```

Hub Class: 

`using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRMVC
{
    public class MyHubMvc : Hub
    {
        public static void Show()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHubMvc>();
            context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
        }
    }
}`

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.connection.myHubMvc.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData();
        };
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tbl');
        var crit = $('#ddlTypes').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:.../api/GetData',
            data: { 'cri': crit },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var tbl = '<table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">';
                tbl += '<tr><th>property1</th><th>property2</th>....<tr>';
                $tbl.empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tbl += '<tr class="w3-light-grey">';
                    tbl += '<td>' + data[i].property1 + '</td>';
                    tbl += '<td>' + data[i].property2 + '</td>';
                    .
                    .
                    .                      
                    tbl += '</tr>';
                }
                tbl += '</table>';
                $tbl.html(tbl);
            },
        })
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();   must be   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { getData();}  addtional to that do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: $.connection.myHubMvc.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData(); this function is not getting called from MyHub class @Stephu

Comment: Remove static on Method Show